Why is my Avatar component not appearing on navbar?
I have been trying to get the avatar icon of user profile image to appear on the navbar but the word 'avatar' just appears instead next to 'Profile'.
The Avatar icon appears perfectly fine with for my post.js
I checked my API's serializer and settings, all this seems correct especially since the avatar is appearing correctly on Post.js.
The API is using dj-rest-auth==6.0.0 and Django==4.2
serializers.py
from dj_rest_auth.serializers import UserDetailsSerializer
from rest_framework import serializers


class CurrentUserSerializer(UserDetailsSerializer):
    profile_id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='profile.id')
    profile_image = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='profile.image.url')

    class Meta(UserDetailsSerializer.Meta):
        fields = UserDetailsSerializer.Meta.fields + (
            'profile_id', 'profile_image'
        )

settings.py
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER': 'pinch_api.serializers.CurrentUserSerializer'
}

Front end NavBar.js;
import Avatar from './Avatar';

<NavLink
  className={styles.NavLink}
  to={`/profiles/${currentUser?.profile_id}`}
>
  <Avatar src={currentUser?.profile_image} text="Profile" height={40} />
</NavLink>


I have checked my API and searched for other solutions but I am not understanding why the avatar would appear for posts but not for navbar.
Does anybody have suggestions what the problem would be?

Could you share your Avatar component? I suspect a few things here - 1. If src is null, it will display the fallback text Profile, but it should render the image when a valid URL is passed.


The issue may be related to how and when data is fetched. If the navbar is rendered before currentUser is populated, the profile_image field might not be available yet. Check the network tab to confirm/rectify.


Console log the currentUser in NavBar.js and ensure the object is populated and contains the correct profile_image URL.


